# How to get distinct values of multiple rows in one cell in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I've used different tables to pull records and placed them into a temp table named #Main.

Then from that temp table, I'm trying to pull up details regarding a user's details including the user's Licence Plate number and the subsequent SAP number with the insurance company for that vehicle.

I've tried to include all the Licence Plates for each account in one cell. I've done the same with the SAP numbers.

**My code is as follows:**

```
Select distinct ST2.AccountNumber
      ,substring(
        (
            Select ', '+ST1.LicPlateNo  AS [text()]
            From #Main ST1
            Where ST1.AccountNumber = ST2.AccountNumber
            ORDER BY ST1.AccountNumber
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [LicPlateNo]

  ,substring(
    (
        Select ', '+ST1.SAPNumber AS [text()]
        From #Main ST1
        Where ST1.AccountNumber = ST2.AccountNumber
        ORDER BY ST1.AccountNumber
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000)SAPNumber

From #Main ST2

ORDER BY CurrentBalance DESC
```

**The Issue I'm facing:**
 Some users have multiple Licence Plate numbers on their account and sometimes have multiple SAP Numbers with the Insurance company for those multiple plates.

I'm getting duplicates in my SAP number field. I need only DISTINCT SAP Numbers for each account.

**EG:**

```
===================================================================
|Account Number|Licence Plates          |SAP Number               |
===================================================================
|ABC1234       |DEF123, XYZ234, CDE345, |A0B1234, B0C4567         |
|              |DEF456                  |                         |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|FGH2345       |MNO123, OPQ456, RST123  |X0Y1234, X0Y1234, X0Y1234|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**So, I wrote code to get the DISTINCT SAP numbers as follows:**

```
,substring(
        (
            Select DISTINCT ', '+ST1.SAPNumber  AS [text()]
            From #Main ST1
            Where ST1.AccountNumber = ST2.AccountNumber
            ORDER BY ST1.AccountNumber
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000)SAPNumber
```

But the above code gave me an error message:
`ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

**EDIT :** 
I edited the last part of my code as per suggestion of Gordon. But I still got an error message: `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

```
,substring(
    (
        Select DISTINCT ', '+ST1.SAPNumber  AS [text()]
        From #Main ST1
        Where ST1.AccountNumber = ST2.AccountNumber
    GROUP BY ST1.SAPNumber
        ORDER BY MAX(ST1.AccountNumber)
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000)SAPNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order by ST1.SAPNumber

You already are doing this for only one Acct

```
,substring(
        (
            Select ', '+ST1.SAPNumber  AS [text()]
            From #Main ST1
            Where ST1.AccountNumber = ST2.AccountNumber
            group by ST1.SAPNumber
            ORDER BY **ST1.SAPNumber**
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000)SAPNumber
```

Comment: get rid of distinct and use group by ST1.SAPNumber. I will edit code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the message is clear.  You can fix it using `group by`:

```
        Select ', '+ST1.SAPNumber  AS [text()]
        From #Main ST1
        Where ST1.AccountNumber = ST2.AccountNumber
        Group by ST1.SAPNumber
        ORDER BY MAX(ST1.AccountNumber)
        For XML PATH ('')
```

Comment: Used the exact code as per your suggestion but still got an error message:     ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @user1777929 . . . There should be no `SELECT DISTINCT`, that's the point of the `GROUP BY`.